# xsl:value-of with a sequence of text nodes: no separator

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I wonder why I am not getting a separator when using `xsl:value-of` with a sequence of text nodes.

Here's a simple way to reproduce the issue:

XML:

```
<input>alpha<br/>bravo<br/>charlie</input>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>alpha bravo charlie</output>
```

Actual output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>alphabravocharlie</output>
```

I know that the processor recognizes that the selection is a sequence of 3 text nodes, because `<xsl:value-of select="count(text())"/>` returns `3` and `<xsl:value-of select="text()[2]"/>` returns `bravo`. But for some reason it does not insert a separator between the individual values.

When I use the `xsl:value` instruction with a sequence of elements, or even with a sequence of strings, I do get the expected separator. It's only with a sequence of text nodes that the behavior is different.

Could this be a quirk of the Saxon processor (I am using Saxon 10.6 HE)?

Comment: Separators are inserted between adjacent atomic values, but not between adjacent nodes. IIRC the rationale for this rather odd rule was (a) so  that `xsl:attribute` would be compatible with XSLT 1.0, and (b) so that `xsl:value-of` would be consistent with `xsl:attribute`.

Comment: It is indeed a very odd rule. I don't see how it can be rationalized by compatibility with XSLT 1.0, when both `xsl:attribute` and `xsl:value-of` return just `alpha` in XSLT 1.0 (as one would expect).

Comment: In XSLT 1.0, `<xsl:attribute name="A"><xsl:text>abc</xsl:text><xsl:text>xyz</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>` returns `A="abcxyz"` with no separator. In 2.0, `xsl:attribute`, `xsl:value-of`, `xsl:comment` etc all take either a sequence of instructions or a select attribute, and they all follow the same rules.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're getting at. But the effect on my example is jarring. It might have been better to restrict this rule to cases where a sequence constructor is present.

Comment: It might or might not. We did spend many hours in the working group trying to find the best solution, but that doesn't mean we succeeded. I'm afraid discussion of how the language could have been better designed is off topic here - it would probably generate a lively discussion on the xsl-list at mulberrytech.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saxon 10 is an XSLT 3 processor, not an XSLT 2 processor. But the version doesn't matter, but let's look at the spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#value-of): "The way in which the value is constructed is specified in 5.7.2 Constructing Simple Content.".

https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#constructing-simple-content: "Adjacent text nodes in the sequence are merged into a single text node".

So this is not a quirk of the processor, just the way the `xsl:value-of` element is defined.

You could use e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="text()/string()"/>` to achieve the result you want, or `<xsl:value-of select="data(text())"/>` is another.

Answer (score 0):

> Could this be a quirk of the Saxon processor (I am using Saxon 10.6 HE)?

Martin already explained the Spec text.

As for a way to achieve the wanted result, there are many ways to do this, one is:

```
    <xsl:sequence select="string-join(text(), ' ')"/>
```